# Jenkins - How to build a master job in slave machine?

Tags: jenkins, master-slave

Initially, I configured the master and slave connection setup in windows machine by launching Java web start method. And then Created a Job in Master machine. Now my question is how to assign a master job to slave machine to build the job. Please provide me the steps to follows. Thanks you.

And please let me know is slave machine requires master machine URL for Connecting Master Slave Connection setup?

Answer (score 0):

You can tie your job on whichever slave you want.
There is option of "Restrict where this project can be run", You can provide jenkins slave name on which this job should always run.

Answer to your last doubt. There is standard methods to connect slave to master, it depends how are you connecting the slave to master.

Comment: yea. In Restrict where this project can be run. There is label Expression. In that field, have to give slave name ?? or something else

Comment: I entered the slave name in the option, "Restrict where this project can be run". After that what can be do? Please help me

Comment: I have to build the Master job in slave machine.

Comment: Is Slave machine need to run the Jenkins server (java -jar jenkins.war) in command prompt?